# Dropwizard Auth - How to return default user if header is not given?

Tags: java, authentication, dropwizard

I want my authorization mechanism to return default user if header for BacicAuth is not specified. I tried to do it this way:

```
@Override
    public Optional<User> authenticate(final BasicCredentials basicCredentials) throws AuthenticationException {

        String email = basicCredentials.getUsername();
        String plaintextPassword = basicCredentials.getPassword();

        final Optional<User> user = Optional.of(userDao.getUserByEmail(email));

        if (user.isPresent()) {
            return user;
            }
        else {
            return Optional.of(defaultUser);
        }
    }
```

But, somehow, I still get 401 when I make a request without proper header.

How can I make it working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if there is no Basic Auth header, a null `BasicCredentials` is passed to a pre-authentication process, which causes an automatic unauthorized error response. So we need to make sure there is a header. To do that, you can register a Jersey filter that performs before the Dropwizard auth filter. There we can add a header with default user name and password.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.annotation.Priority;
import javax.ws.rs.Priorities;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders;
import org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.Base64;

@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION - 100)
public class PreAuthenticationFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext request) throws IOException {
        boolean hasValidHeader = false;
        if (request.getHeaders().containsKey(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION)) {
            final String header = request.getHeaderString(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
            if (header.toLowerCase().startsWith("basic")) {
                hasValidHeader = true;
            }
        }
        if (!hasValidHeader) {
            final String defaultUser = "defaultUser";
            final String defaultPassword = "defaultPassword";
            final String base64 = Base64.encodeAsString(defaultUser + ":" + defaultPassword);
            request.getHeaders().putSingle(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Basic " + base64);
        }
    } 
}
```

Then just register it with DW `env.jersey().register(PreAuthenticationFilter.class);`

Comment: Question is, if you use the filter, why not do auth in that filter right away? In my opinion, the DW auth is a bit flawed as in it takes away a bit of control that I feel is important. I prefer doing auth in the filter over using DW's approach. A lot of people have encountered the same issue I think.

Comment: There are a couple of filters in the authN/authZ chain. First is the authenticaion filter. Dropwizard uses your authenticator in this filter. The the Jersey authorization (rolesallowed) filter, which calls your authorizer. So different filters handle different things. Maybe what you see flawed is not the process, but the implementation of the authentication filter. For you particular use case, yes I agree it's a burden to have to use this work around. But that's just how it's implemented.

Comment: You can see [here in the source](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/v0.9.2/dropwizard-auth/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/auth/basic/BasicCredentialAuthFilter.java#L33) where it check for a header. If it's not there, then throws the exception.